# Segmentation error while printing a histogram

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Ok so I wanted to do this question :"Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input"(Exercise 1-13 of the book C programming by Brian and dennis ritchie).
In this code I am printing only the tally of various word lengths(as its my first attempt).

This program compiles fine but while running the code I am getting this Segmentation fault(code dump) error.
What's wrong with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void read(char input[]);
void draw(int i[]);
main()
{
    int i,k,l;
    int len[16];
    char input[100];
    read(input);
    i=k=l=0;
    for(l=0;l<=15;l++)
    {
        len[l]=0;
    }
    while(input[i]!='/0')
    {   
        if(input[i]!='\n'&&input[i]!='\t'&&input[i]!=' ')
        {   k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {   len[k]=len[k]+1;
            k=0;
            i++;    
        }
    }
    draw(len);
    return 0;
}

void read(char c[])
{
    int i=0;
    int a;
    while((a=getchar())!=EOF)
    {   c[i]=a;
        i++;
    }
    c[i]='\0';
}

void draw(int len[])
{   int i=0;
    printf("Length\tWords\n");
    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
    printf("%6d\t%6d\n",i,len[i]);
}
```

Comment: You might want to use the debugger and at least give us more information on the error code :o

Comment: @Papergay Sorry I'm a bit new with c, how would I do that? I'm just working on linux terminal.

Comment: Do a Google search for e.g. "gdb tutorial".

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to avoid using the name `read` for your own function. There is already a function with that name in the system.

Comment: Take [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger)! And [this](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~caspl102/wiki.files/lab2/gdb-intro.html). And [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html), this, [this](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/gcc.html) and thiiiiis.

Comment: @Papergay Here are the results
      "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080484f2 in main () at Histogram.c:22
22   { len[k]=len[k]+1;"

Comment: Do `print k` to see what value the variable `k` has.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(l=0;l<=15;l++)
{
    len[l]=0;
}
```

Your array is of type`int [15]` so you are accessing an element outside the array.

You have the exact same issue in the `draw` function here:

```
for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
```

Also:

```
char a;
while((a=getchar())!=EOF)
```

`a` should be of type `int` and not `char`. See this for the explanation:

http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: You are right, just changed the code to int[16] but still the problem is there.

Comment: @Vicky also see the second part of the answer

Comment: Did all you said, still the same error. Thanks anyways I'll try debugging

Answer (score 0):

one error i could notice is in `for(l=0;l<=15;l++)`. it should be `for(l=0;l<15;l++)`.

`int len[15]` means `len` is int array of size 15 with valid locations as `len[0], len[1], ... len[14]` but here you are accessing `len[15]` which is `undefined` and may cause `segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `read`, you do not check the length of the input, so if your input is larger than the number of entries in `c` you will write in memory not belonging to you.

**Edit:**

After you checked in a debugger it's easier to search for the reason of the error, and if you look at that `while` loop you will see it quite clearly:

```
while(input[i]!='/0')
```

You compare a character in `input` against an illegal character literal. You are using forward slash, but it should be a backward slash: `'\0'`. Actually, your should give a warning about a multi-character character literal.

Comment: But I am only typing around 4 words at runtime so that should be fine, no?

Comment: @Vicky As long as it's less than 99 characters in those words.

Comment: @Vicky Updated my answer with the (now) obvious answer.

Comment: Thanks yeah it did give that warning. Whats the difference between '\0' and '/0'

Comment: @Vicky `'\0'` is a single character, the so-called NULL-terminator and is used to terminate strings (as you apparently know already). `'/0'` are two different characters, and in a character literal is not really legal.

Answer (score 0):

This line contains an error:

```
while(input[i]!='/0')
```

and causes your code to access memory not owned by your program.

It should be:

```
while(input[i]!='\0')
```

as the string terminating char is '\0'.

Comment: Man you are gold. Sorry didn't see your comment before.
I mean its working now, cheers.